# how to use constructor parameter in companion object

Tags: android, kotlin

Hello i have a class which has timeZoneId as constructor parameter, I want to use timeZoneId in the companionObject, how can I do that please

```
@Singleton
class ChInteractor @Inject constructor(
    val timeZoneId: ZoneId
) {
       companion object {
        fun getNextSessionDateText(
            clock: Clock,
            targetDaySeconds: Int
        ): String {
            val date = LocalDateTime.now(clock)
            val nowDaySeconds = date.toLocalTime().toSecondOfDay()
             val newPastSeconds = nowToMidnightSeconds(timeZoneId) + targetDaySeconds
             return "something"
        }

        private val simpleDateFormat = SimpleDateFormat("EEEE dd MMM")
        const val HOUR_SECONDS = 3600
        const val MINUTE_SECONDS = 60
    }
}
```

Could you please suggest how to access timeZoneId in companion object please

Thanks in advance
R

Comment: You need to move the function out of the companion object.

Comment: Is it not possible to achieve this with function in the companion object as, I am using the function from a composable

Comment: Inject this class into your activity or fragment. Then you can pass the instance to your Composable.

Answer (score 2):

Companion object is unrelated to any specific instance of `ChInteractor`. It is like a static scope in Java. As a result, it can't access member properties of `ChInteractor`.

If you need to access member properties, you have to make the function itself a member function of `ChInteractor`, not a function of the companion object.